# Spring Cloud Stream Functional Manual Acknowledgement - KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT not available

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Webflux and Spring Cloud Streams Functional Interfaces, to handle my kafka processing.

If i do the processing sequentially and if I kill the application, it gives back the message for processing which works as expected as there is no drop of messages. However if i try to do parallel, it seems to be acknowledging to Kafka which is understandable as it is now a separate thread, hence want to turn to manual acknowledge.

My Code:

1. application.yml (relevant portions)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          autoAddPartitions: true
          minPartitionCount: 2         
      bindings:
          receiver-in-0:
               binder: kafka
              destination: topic-1
              content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
              group: input-group-1
              consumer:
                  autoCommitOffset: false
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition: receiver
```

2. Receiver Code

```
public Consumer<Flux<Message<String>>> receiver() throws IOException {
        return (sink -> {
            sink
            .onBackpressureBuffer()
            .parallel(4)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .subscribe((record)->{  
                Flux<Action> executor = new 
                           //Internal code which does transformation and provides a flux for execution (names changed)
 IncomingMessage().process(record);

                if(executor != null) {
                    Disposable disposable=null;
                    disposable= executor.subscribe(
                            (action)->{

                                try {
                                   //Process execute does the processing on the modified data (names changed)
                                    Process.execute(action);
                                    Acknowledgment acknowledgment = record.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
                                    if(acknowledgment !=null) {
                                        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception e) {

                                log.fatal(e.getMsg());
                                }
                            },
                            (e)->{

                                log.fatal(e.getMsg());
                                }
                            });
                    if(disposable != null) {
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }

                }

            });

        });
    }
```

Here the line `record.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);` always gives null, so I am assuming that the `autoCommitOffset: false` is not working, i tried putting the below configuration also in the binding section but to no avail.

```
 receiver-in-0:
               binder: kafka
              destination: topic-1
              content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
              group: input-group-1
              autoCommitOffset: false
```

My requirement is that if i kill the application, even in parallel scenario it should continue to read the messages from the first non acknowledged message.

Comment: Please don't cross post the same question between gitter and SO. It's wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Oleg Zhurakousky : I haven't. can you share the link in gitter? If it is being published i will follow that.

Comment: Async processing (Flux) with Kafka is fraught with difficulty - Kafka does not acknowledge discrete records; it only maintains a partition offset for a consumer group. If he record `@2` completes first and the server fails before `@1` is processed; you will lose record `@1`.

Comment: So If i understand , I should not do parallel processing for records , Flux though async is still sequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in not getting the acknowledge header is because of the incorrect position of the tags. As it is purely a kafka binder property . Added the following property

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
           receiver-in-0:
              consumer:
                   autoCommitOffset: false
```

The channel name should be the same as the channel name in the function call.
alternatively the default, can be set.

```
 spring:
    cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
           default:
            consumer:
               autoCommitOffset: false
```

However parallel processing of the incoming flux may not be good idea as messages can get dropped as some later message can get acknowledged. It would require more logic for acknowledging than just setting the parameter acknowledging.